# Export the Lambda ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I would like to export my Lambda ARN that I created using the serverless framework, as I need to use this ARN in other CF template

I defined Outputs and Export in my serverless.yml file.

```
resources:
  Outputs:
    ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn:
      Export:
        Name: MyServiceARN
```

It's working fine.

However, the export contains the lambda version ARN (i.e arn:aws:lambda:region:12345:function:servicename:2).

This is causing issue as this ARN is used by other CF thus cannot be updated.

"Export MyServiceArn cannot be updated as it is in use by xyz"

Is there a way to get the ARN without the version number ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show the complete `ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn` output. You are missing the `value` attribute.

Comment: I actually didn't define the value attribute, and it's doing it already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
resources:
  Outputs:
    ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn:
      Export:
        Name: MyServiceARN
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt: ServiceLambdaFunction.Arn
```

Comment: Not working for me.  ` Template format error: The Value field of every Outputs member must evaluate to a String and not a Map.` This keeps showing. I have changed to almost same as yours.

Comment: Does not for me neither...The SLS version I am using is 1.40.0
 ` Template format error: The Value field of every Outputs member must evaluate to a String and not a Map.`

Comment: Try using `Value:  Ref: ServiceLambdaFunction`

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

In response to the first comment, I'd like to give some context to this answer: the author asked how to export *the ARN without the version number?*

The actual problem lies in the **Key** that was used to export the function ARN: **ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn**

```yaml
resources:
  Outputs:
    ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn: # <- CloudFormation Key
      Export:
        Name: MyServiceARN
```

The Serverless Framework, by default, exports each Lambda function with their Qualified Function ARN (i.e., ARN plus version suffix) as CloudFormation Stack Output. That means, the Lambda function **hello** will be exported as **HelloLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn**, even if you don't define any outputs in the resources section. Just check the CloudFormation Stack output of a deployed Serverless service:

[image]

That means, Serverless will overwrite your output declaration **ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn** with their own declaration during deployment. By the way, that is also the reason that it was working even though no actual **Value** was specified.

In order to export the *ARN without version number*, you must manually declare an additional output with a different **Key**, for example **HelloLambdaFunctionArn** or **ServiceLambdaFunctionArn** (remove *Qualified* from the string), and reference the ARN as **Value**:

```yaml
resources:
  Outputs:
    ServiceLambdaFunctionArn: # <- CloudFormation Key
      Value: !GetAtt ServiceLambdaFunction.Arn # <- CloudFormation Value
      Export: 
        Name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-MyServiceARN
```

---

This has worked for me:

Export in first serverless stack with a unique export name `<stack>-<stage>-TransformDataLambdaArn`:

```yaml
service: first-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-1
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

functions:
  myLambda:
    handler: src/handlers/myLambda.handle

resources:
  Outputs:
    MyLambdaFunctionArn:
      Description: 'ARN will be imported by other stacks'
      Value: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunction.Arn
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-MyLambdaArn
```

And import in the second stack with the same stage like this:

```yaml
Fn::ImportValue: first-service-${self:custom.stage}-MyLambdaArn
```

Comment: Oh god. Somehow this worked. But can you give a little context for this answer to understand what is happening behind the scenes? My idea was that, you can export with any name (say 'exportedArn') by giving value as '!GetAtt LogicalResourceId.Arn'. Then while importing we have to use the same name 'exportedArn'. For some reason, it's not working.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Update 07-2020

This question is still valid, and the accepted answer did not work for me with serverless 1.74.1. My use case was to export a custom authorizer lambda (as a separate service) to other services.

Here is what worked for me:

```
resources:
  Outputs:
    ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn:
      Export:
        Name: MyServiceARN
```

You don't need a reference to value, the arn should be exported with just the name.

Then to use the Export in another service:

```
authorizer:
  name: MyServiceARN
  arn:
    Fn::ImportValue: MyServiceARN
```

The "name" added to this ended up being required for the custom authorizer use case.

Comment: will not work, every Export needs Value member

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
!GetAtt MyCreatedResource.Arn
```

E.g.

```
Outputs: 
  FluentBitVerifyRole:
    Description: ARN of the verification role
    Value: !GetAtt FluentBitVerifyRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

nah , just add   versionFunctions: false inside your serverless.yml 
inside the provider

like this

```
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  versionFunctions: false
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```